# How I can remove the name of youtube Video?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embed

i need to remove the title of the embed video in youtube,
i know that showinfo is deprecated but 
What other options can you use to remove the title or at least hide it?

Comment: None. https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/9paamr/removing_a_youtube_title_from_an_embedded_video/ - So by adding `?modestbranding=1` you can only remove the bottom right corner *"YouTube"*  when hovering the embed video...